# How to run .clp file in jess

Tags: batch-file, jess

I have installed jess trial version in linux. I am trying run one of the example .clp file. I have used batch as there in jess documentation. But I am getting an error. like,

```
Jess> (batch "examples/jess/sticks.clp")
Jess reported an error in routine batch
        while executing (batch "examples/jess/sticks.clp").
  Message: Cannot open file.
  Program text: ( batch "examples/jess/sticks.clp" )  at line 14.

Nested exception is:
examples/jess/sticks.clp (No such file or directory)
```

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you - instead of starting Jess or after terminating Jess - do a `ls examples/jess/sticks.clp` at the shell prompt?

Answer (score 1):

Jess doesn't behave any different from most other programs: a relative pathname is interpreted relative to the working directory in effect when the program was started. So, if you have done

```
$ pwd
/home/youser/play
$ /extra/Jess/bin/jess
Jess> (batch "examples/jess/sticks.clp")
```

Jess expects that file to be in /home/youser/play/examples/jess/sticks.clp. Most likely, it isn't. On my system, I might have success using

```
Jess> (batch "/extra/Jess/examples/jess/sticks.clp")
```

as I have unzipped everything below /extra.